# How to add multiple components to parent component in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Let us assume we have 100 components. We usually add the component selector/name in HTML tags to the template of the parent component.But here we have 100's of components, so is there any dynamic way to add them??

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, could you give an example of what you are currently doing manually?

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue/)

In that example pie, bar are the components. We add them using <pie></pie> and <bar></bar> tags respectively in main component.But what if we have 100 components like that. Is there any dynamic way to add them.

Comment: I still don't get it, there's no pie or bar in the example you posted.

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/23LajuuL/1/)

In that example pie, bar are the components. We add them using <pie></pie> and <bar></bar> tags respectively in main component.But what if we have 100 components like that. Is there any dynamic way to add them


**I'm so sorry I forgot to save it **

Comment: So you have 100 different components? Max Sinev posted an answer that should work in that case, but you still need to write a list of all the components obviously. It might be possible that there's a better way than having those 100 components in the first place, but hard to tell with the given info.

Answer (score 3):

There is a  Vue tag:

```
<component :is="myComponent"></component>
```

Where **myComponent** is component name or whole component object. You can create array with component names and render them with **v-for** dynamically.
See [Vue Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) for details about dynamic component.

Comment: This is a nice solution. did not know it existed.

Comment: `<component v-for="comp in components" :key="comp" :is="comp"></component>`
`components=['pie','bar']`

This didn't work

Comment: Do you register components somehow with `Vue.component` or `components` section in parent component?

Comment: Yes I have added them.

`<pie></pie>
<bar></bar>`

this worked well

Comment: Before use them in markup you should register components with one of provided ways in code. Here jsfiddle with example how to achieve that: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/336240/)

Comment: Try to use div, b, span etc instead of your custom elements. If those don't work either you're doing something wrong, https://jsfiddle.net/qxaodc74/

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to dynamically add components.

In general there is three things.
1. instantiate the component
2. mount the component
3. add it to the dom tree

```
var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(Component)
var instance = new ComponentClass() //instantiate
instance.$mount()  //mount
this.$refs.container.appendChild(instance.$el) //add to dom
```

Comment: Ah, I might have misunderstood the question and answered if it is possible to programmatically add components.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this. The `<component :is>` trick is handy to know, but this is a bit like getting a wedding invitation with the name of the bride on a sticky label - not convincing. You need to commit yourself sometime. The template with lots of of `<component :is>` tags will be *impossible to understand and maintain*.

Comment: I extremely agree with you, `component` is useful in just few situations.  But the solution is to apply just **single** component tag with `v-for` directive that will improve code understanding instead of adding 100s of similar components in markup(causes increasing app bundle size as well).

Answer (score 0):

This worked!!!!!

```
<div v-for="comp in components" :key="comp">
    <component :is="comp"></component>
 </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't need `div` wrapper in general, please see my jsfiddle link in my answer comment. I think you can mark my answer as correct one.